# css support in flex textarea and text interaction

Tags: html, css, apache-flex, textarea, interactive

I'm sorry if it is a general question, but I cannot find clear informations about this topic. I would like to render rich text content or specific HTML, in a mobile environment, and to call some custom actionscript functions when clicking on some text. My first idea was to use a textarea with StyleableTextField component, but its css support is poor (only a few tags are supported).

I don't know any other option, considering that Text Layout Framework is not recommended for mobile use due to performance reasons (is it true? I don't even know where to find a detailed tutorial about it).

My layout is very simple, a 2 column liquid layout:

```
//css style definitions:

.wrapper {width: 100%; float: left;} .sx {margin-right: 10%;} .dx {float: right; width: 10%; font-size: 25%;}


//html to render
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='dx'>123 note</div>
<div class='sx'><b>Hello</b><i>world!</i></div>
</div>
```

, clicking on "123 note" I would like to call a function defined in my "fx Script" tag.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried to make some script execute when an element is clicked on? Why no “javascript” in the question tags?

Comment: My questions are: which is the best usage of a textarea to render richt text or complex layout and to execute some custom functions clicking on some text of it. What I found is that: StyleableTextField Component supports only HTML 1 and Text Layout Framework is not recommended for mobile development. Is there any other option? If I have to go with TLF, is there any tutorial or example I can study to provide complex layout and interaction with text? (I don't even know if javascript is the solution and eventually how to use it)

Answer (score 0):

Look into using [StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html).  You basically get a full browser to display your HTML content.

Also of note is Judah Frangipane's [WebView wrapper](https://github.com/monkeypunch3/flexcapacitor) - it simplifies usage for StageWebView.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks but I cannot see any chanche to call a function defined in my "fx Script" tag, clicking on the text (for example in "123 note"), something similar to asfunction used in HTML text fields that allows an HREF link to call an ActionScript function. In the documentation: "The StageWebView  class provides no interaction between ActionScript and the HTML content".
Basically, I would need 2 features: rendering complex layout (html and css is just an option) and providing interaction as above.

Comment: There's a loophole that lets you do interaction between Actionscript and the HTML.  If you load the HTML document from a URL, then setting `document.location` in javascript will trigger an event in Actionscript.  Similarly, you can call javascript functions from Actionscript by setting the location on the `StageWebView` to e.g. `javascript:functionCall()`.  It quickly gets very complex, but it might do the trick in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks Brian! Is there any example of this somewhere?